# My button does make me go to the "playscene"swift sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been trying to do this for a long time. My problem is when I use this code (I learned of on YouTube), it gives me an error on line 5 where it declares the `SKView`. It
gives me this error

> Downcast from 'SKView?' to 'SKView' only unwraps optionals; did you
>   mean use '!'?

Here is my code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    //making the scene vars
    var scene =  PlayScene(size: self.size)

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
         let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replcace this line:

```
    let skView = self.view as SKView
```

with this line:

```
    let skView = self.view!
```